# Converting java.sql.timestamp to Json format

Tags: java, sql, json, jackson

I have a 
`private java.sql.Timestamp myDate;`
In some model (POJO) class. Is it possible to convert it (by jackson) to something like that:
`Wed, 23 Nov 2016 20:37:09 GMT`
?
I know that I may use something like `@JsonProperty`, however I can't deal with format of this one.  Moreover, keep in mind that I not only send JSON, but also receive the same JSON.
Thank in advance!

Comment: basically you want to convert java timestamp to formatted string which goes in as a value for one of your json property. right ?

Comment: did you try formatting the Date object???

Comment: The problem is that I using automatical mechanisms of spring - something like ResponseBody (jackson and other similar stories)

Comment: even if you use spring request body you can still extract the date, format and set it back.

Comment: Can you be more precisely ?  Set it back on sq.Timestamp type after format ?  Seems to be hard

Answer (score 5):

You can add a custom serializer for your timestamp field.

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Timestamp arg0, JsonGenerator arg1, SerializerProvider arg2)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(arg0);
        arg1.writeString(formattedDate);

    }

}
```

Than add @JsonSerialize on your variable in POJO,

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
    public Timestamp timestamp;
```

After that when you serializes it like this:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(//YOUR OBJECT HERE//);

You will get something like this :

```
{"timestamp":"Tue, 6 Dec 2016 19:06:33 IST"}
```

And it will deserialize back this passed JSON to your timestamp field in your POJO.

Answer (score 2):

@JsonFormat annotation as follows, can be used on POJO java.sql.Timestamp members:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", timezone = "GMT+2")
```

For MySQL TIMESTAMP record:

```
2018-04-30 14:10:13
```

Output is:

```
Mon, 30 Apr 2018 14:10:13 GMT+02:00
```

NOTE: This applies to Jackson 2.0 or newer

Answer (score -1):

convert your timestamp using the following format

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

a sample code will be :

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());

        System.out.println(ts);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(ts));
```

will print out

```
2016-11-23 15:55:22.291
Wed, 23 Nov 2016 15:55:22 EST
```